# Prompt command not working in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried many variations of the script below, including changing the syntax and using window.prompt, but can't find a way to get the prompt to work.

Note: If there are errors in my other code (html), feel free to point them out, but focus on the JS - the page is loading perfectly with all elements, but the script simply doesn't run on a mobile device, even though it ran perfectly when I didn't have a prompt. Can you please help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>program</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
 <script>
      var accesskey="config";
      if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
 Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 var attempt=window.prompt("Mobile browsers are not currently supported. If 
 you are a developer, enter the access key.")

      if(accesskey!=attempt)
      {
          alert("Bye!");
          window.location("https://google.com);
       }
                  else
                  {
                  console.log("Authenticated");
                  }
    }
     </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do you actually have line breaks within your regular expression and within your string? Also `window.location` is not a function and it’s missing a closing `"`.

Comment: Also Missing closing `"` in `window.location();`

Comment: @Xufox Yes, I do.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Awesome, thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: Put your prompt text all on the same line.

Comment: Then remove those line breaks. And change the `location` change to `window.location = "https://google.com/";`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Do you know how to check the browser console? All of these errors would be pointed out there.

Comment: To everyone who told me to fix the URL, thanks for your help. Works now. Will check JS console in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have a number of line breaks / spaces in your regular expression and **[`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)** message.
- **[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)** is not a function; simply assign the URL to it.
- You are missing a closing `"` at the end of `google.com`.

Fixing up these three issues produces the following working example:

```js
var accesskey = "config";
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  var attempt = window.prompt("Mobile browsers are not currently supported. If you are a developer, enter the access key.")
  if (accesskey != attempt) {
    alert("Bye!");
    window.location = "https://google.com";
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Prompt is working as below your `regex` is having line break and also its false so i have forced it to be true here. 
Also `window.location("https://google.com);` is missing closing `"` and its a property not a function you should do  `window.location="https://google.com"`

```js
var accesskey="config";
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || true)   
 var attempt=window.prompt("Mobile browsers are not currently supported. If you are a developer, enter the access key.")

      if(accesskey!=attempt)
      {
          alert("Bye!");
          window.location ="https://google.com";
       }
                  else
                  {
                  console.log("Authenticated");
                  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>program</title>
   </head>
   <body>
 
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Will momentarily, but still encountering an error - after entering an incorrect or null code, it still redirects me to the website itself without going to Google. Let me debug.

Comment: let me know what error you are getting... it might be a same origin issue